# why is the passive form used here つなみで流された but not with 台風でこわれた、地震で壊れた

Tags: passive-form

in this paragraph 「鎌倉に高さ11メートルの大仏がある。大仏が作られたときは建物の中にありましたが、今は建物がありません。どうして建物がなくなったのでしょうか。台風でこわれた、地震で壊れた、つなみで流されたなど、いろいろ言われている。」why is the passive form used with tsunami.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

壊れる is an intransitive verb that means "to collapse/break", but 流す is a transitive verb that means "to wash (something) away". 建物が津波で流した ("The building washed (something) away using a tsunami") makes no sense. 建物が津波で流された ("The building was washed away by a tsunami") is the correct sentence.

Comment: My impression is that the OP is wondering why there is a discrepancy between the framing of the two actions. In other words, why did the writer choose 壊れる + 流される and not 壊される + 流される or 壊れる + 流れる? Perhaps I read more into the question than there was though.

Comment: @Leebo - If that's what the OP was asking, I would say that 壊された sounds too "intentional" and makes you feel the existence of a willful agent behind it, whereas 流れた sounds too "spontaneous". I think this has to do with the fact that 壊れる is a "destructive" verb while 流れる is not.